# Reading text and storing them into dataframe time complexity

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to

- reading data file line by line
- store them into pandas dataframe
- outputting to csv

using **Python**.

The problem is that it takes too long to execute these code. It took about 1 hour to get up to 2% mark for file with 900,000ish rows.

This is example file I am reading

[image: Example Output]

There will be n CAJ rows, and 61 columns

Each value for criteria keeps the same until new one comes up. (There is only one header for one file, multiple FIN, and on...)

First I am using

```
with open(filename) as fn:
    content = fn.readlines()
```

To read each line from the file.

Then I create empty(na) data frame using pandas by counting each CAJ lines.

```
row_count = 0

for line in content:
    if(line[0:3] =='CAJ'):
        row_count+=1

print('There is ' + str(row_count) + ' rows.')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(row_count), columns=columns)
```

(Columns are the names of columns for each criteria)

Next, I create temporary list of values for each row.

```
row_list = ['']*len(columns)
row_list[0:2] = hdr[1:3]
```

Finally, I check for each criteria for each line and store into temporary. If I end up with CAJ, I modified current row of data frame and proceed.

```
row_counter = 0

for line in content:
    if(line[0:3] =='FIN'):
        fin_cur = line.split(',')[1:-1]
        row_list[2:13] = fin_cur
    elif(line[0:3] =='PRV'):
        prv_cur = line.split(',')[1:-1]
        row_list[13] = prv_cur[0]
    elif(line[0:3] == 'PLB'):
        plm_cur = line.split(',')[1:-1]
        row_list[14:33] = plm_cur
    elif(line[0:3] == 'CLM'):
        clm_cur = line.split(',')[1:-1]
        row_list[33:42] = clm_cur
    elif(line[0:3] == 'CAJ'):
        caj_cur = line.split(',')[1:-1]
        row_list[42:61] = caj_cur
        df.loc[row_counter]=row_list
        row_counter+=1
```

I thought it would be O(n) but it takes way longer than I expected.

I am pretty sure there could be better way to managed these file into csv file.

What would be the best way to approach these files?

**EDIT**

This is example csv output.

[image: output]

Comment: IIUC, why don't you just read the file and send it to a dataframe and then conditionally filter the dataframe? You could run a test with a small subset of your data. Currently you are employing way too much indexing. Your file is already comma-delimited, use that to your advantage (`pd.read_csv()`).

Comment: correct, just specify nrows when you read in the csv to do testing.  Also we have no idea what your data looks like.  How many columns do you have?  What kind of data is it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The thing is that each line in original file does not represents each row in dataframe. Each line does not represents new row, it keep constant value until next criteria (e.g FIN, CLM, ...). Also `pd.read_csv()` gives me error with my files.

Comment: Your comment isn't really helpful in terms of better understanding your question. I'm confident you can modify the dataframe in the manner you want AFTER you create it with `pd.read_csv()`. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Every row has different number of columns (number of comma separated data). That is why I thought it wouldn't make sense with `pd.read_csv()`. The error is `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 5, saw 21`.